# What does the number represent when printing a socket in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock

```
SOCKET sampleSocket;
cout << sampleSocket << endl;
// End up with a number
```

I noticed that when I use cout to print a socket, I receive a number--what does that number represent and how can I retrieve it outside of using cout?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/socket-data-type-2

Comment: Thanks! What data type would a socket be analogous to then. I know HANDLE is an unsigned integer, but what would a SOCKET type be?

Comment: It's probably the index in a table hidden in the process information for your program. In this table with be the actual socket control block that's full of all the little implementation details that you don't give a crap about. But frankly, it could be just about anything. Whatever it is and however it's stored, that number is your key to looking up the *real* socket information from somewhere.

Comment: @ZacharyZhu If you look at the actual declaration of `SOCKET`, you will see that it is just a typedef for `UINT_PTR`, which is a pointer-sized unsigned integer.

Comment: @user4581301 on Windows, a `SOCKET` is an actual kernel object, just like a file, pipe, etc, where the `SOCKET` contains a handle (equivalent to a pointer) to the actual object. It is not an index to a table that is local to the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Winsock applications, a socket descriptor is not a file descriptor and must be used with the Winsock functions.
> [...] Because the SOCKET type is unsigned, compiling existing source code from, for example, a UNIX environment may lead to compiler warnings about signed/unsigned data type mismatches.

(See [Socket Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/socket-data-type-2))

From this documentation we can gather that it is an `unsigned` data type. However, the exact integer type remains implementation-defined. It will likely be a 32-bit or 64-bit `unsigned` integer.

Comment: `SOCKET` is just a typedef for `UINT_PTR`, you can see this declared in `winsock.h` and `winsock2.h`

Comment: @RemyLebeau this might be the implementation, but it's not specified that it has to be a `UINT_PTR`. `uint64_t` might be defined as `unsigned long long` on your platform right now, but that doesn't mean it always is.